# How to collapse gallery and strip when no data found in database

Tags: javascript, velo

I am using the below code and want elements to collapse when there is no content in the dataset. Right now, if there is an element that is not in the dataset, it creates a large white space at the bottom of the page.

Current code:

```js
$w.onReady(() => {
    $w("#dynamicDataset").onReady(() => {
 // Gets the current item properties and stores them in a variable called item
 const item = $w("#dynamicDataset").getCurrentItem();

if (!item.gallery){

 $w("#gallery1").collapse()

} else {

$w("#gallery1").expand()

}



if (!item.mainImage2){

 $w("#gallery2").collapse()

} else {

$w("#gallery2").expand()

}



if (!item.stripImageLeft){

 $w("#columnStrip13").collapse()

} else {

$w("#columnStrip13").expand()

}



if (!item.processGallery){

 $w("#gallery3").collapse()

} else {

$w("#gallery3").expand()

}


if (!item.processGallery){

 $w("#columnStrip12").collapse()

} else {

$w("#gallery3").expand()

}


if (!item.videoUrl){

 $w("#videoPlayer1").collapse()

} else {

$w("#videoPlayer1").expand()

}
    });
});
```

Here is an example with all elements filled in, and it looks great.
[Exmple 1](https://www.jkaedesign.com/Projects/Yerba-Buena-HS---Student-Union-%26-Administration-Building)

Here is an example with all the white space at the bottom:
[Example 2](https://www.jkaedesign.com/Projects/Donner-Lake)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this comment on the Velo Forum](https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/main/comment/5ebceafc36e45e002d0b35e4) for an explanation.

Basically you need to make sure your footer is sticking to the last element on the page. If required:

1. Cut the gallery element using Ctrl + X (for Windows)
2. Pull up the handle of the footer and stick it to the last element on the page (after the gallery has been removed)
3. Ctrl + V (for Windows) to reintroduce the gallery element and make sure you don't create a gap between the gallery and footer this time by manually pulling the footer handle downwards

Tip 1: Introduce transparent boxes to make sure all elements are stacked upon (stick to) each other to avoid this issue

Tip 2: Do not fill your gallery with images by default, keep the gallery empty